# Validation Excpetion error when calling the DeleteItem operation in aws cli for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I got a table in dynamodb

> aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name work

```
{
"Table": {
    "TableArn": "../work",
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "id",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5,
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5
    },
    "TableSizeBytes": 0,
    "TableName": "work",
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "KeySchema": [
        {
            "KeyType": "HASH",
            "AttributeName": "id"
        }
    ],
    "ItemCount": 0,
    "CreationDateTime": 1505847222.951
}
```

and my data was like

id(P.K)  location

1   location1

2   location1

3   location2

And in my key.json

```
{
    "location": {"S": "location1"}
}
```

And when I

> aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name work --key file://key.json

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "id": {"S": "location1"}
}
```

You key.json is in wrong format.

Check the documentation,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/delete-item.html

Comment: when I copied your format it was 



An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: Looks like ValidationException is not occuring anymore. Looks like your Role is not allowed to access dyanamodb. Check it out in the forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=737198

Comment: I took the proper permissions, and I get no errors, but the data is not deleted in dynamodb

Comment: And the schema you defined is not deleting any data from dynamodb

Comment: What is the response do you get back from the system ?

Comment: There is no response and not deletion in the database, it just enters into new line.

Can you give me schema to delete all the data which contains location1.